# Remove 'None' from output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove all the phrases that do not belong to the French language. I tried with the langdetect library (and without pandas, unfortunately)

**CSV file**

```
message
Je suis fatiguée
The book is on the table
Il fait chaud aujourd'hui!
They are sicks
La vie est belle
```

**Script:**

```
import csv
from langdetect import detect

with open('ddd.csv', 'r') as file:
    fichier = csv.reader(file)

    for line in fichier:
        if line[0] != '':
            message = line[0]

            def detecteur_FR(message):
                #We need to turn the column into a list of lists.
                message_list = [comments for comments in message.split('\n')]
                for text in message_list:
                    if detect(text) == 'fr':
                        message_FR = text
                        return message_FR

            print(detecteur_FR(message))
```

**My output:**

```
None
Je suis fatiguée
None
Il fait chaud aujourd hui!
None
La vie est belle
```

I want:

```
Je suis fatiguée
Il fait chaud aujourd hui!
La vie est belle
```

How could I remove 'None'?

Comment: I don't think you should define your function there, move it to another scope (proably global)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just add a check before printing:

```
result = detecteur_FR(message)
if result is not None:
    print(result)
```

Comment: They currently short circuit via `return` on the first french line, but they might actually want all of them

Answer (score 2):

You're redefining the function in every iteration step of the loop.

Instead, define it once (globally) and only call it inside the loop:

```
import csv
from langdetect import detect

def detecteur_FR(message):
    # We need to turn the column into a list of lists.
    for text in message.split('\n'):
        if detect(text) == 'fr':
            return text

with open('ddd.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in csv.reader(file):
        if line[0] != '':
            result = detecteur_FR(line[0])
            if result:
                 print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you do the comparison before printing the message?

```
convt_message = detecteur_FR(message)
if convt_message:
    print(convt_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the Nones because you do not strip the '\n' of the end of each line

try this:

```
import csv
from langdetect import detect

def detecteur_FR(message):
     #We need to turn the column into a list of lists.
     message_list = [comments for comments in message.split('\n')]
     for text in message_list:
         if detect(text) == 'fr':
              message_FR = text
              print message_FR   

with open('ddd.csv', 'r') as file:
    fichier = csv.reader(file)

    for line in fichier:
        if line.strip() != '':
            message = line[0]
            detecteur_FR(message)
```

Comment: No, they're getting Nones because some lines don't contain any french text, therefore never returning anything explicitly.

Comment: true, so the options are printing inside the function, or verify that the output is not None